# Option to fetch results based on a count and offset

Tags: ldap

Is there a way to fetch results from LDAP using a count and an offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entries returned to search requests are never  ordered in any way, nor are attributes, attribute options, or attribute values. Some servers support VLV and server-side sorting, however.

For more information, see [LDAP search](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/).

Comment: Some servers also support attribute value sorting.

Comment: Count and offset here should be used in a way where the user needs the number of entries equal to count starting at the offset numbered entry. Ordering is not a issue.